# How to add Style on click in React

Tags: reactjs

How can I manipulate css value through function.

Once click on button and add tranform in to `.box` div.

Here is the `JS` code, which need to convert into `React`

**Javascript**

```
var x = 1024; // min value
var y = 9999; // max value

var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;
document.getElementById("box").style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
```

**React 16**

```
myfunction=()=>{
 var x = 1024; // min value
 var y = 9999; // max value
 let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;
 let tranf = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
 var ani = {
  transform: tranf,
 };
}

<div className="box" style={this.ani}>

<button className="spin" onClick={this.myfunction}>
 Spin
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}
```

**Ref**
Building this into React.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gcz5RM-imJ8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    animationStyle: null,
    hasAnimationStarted: false,
  };
  
  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({ hasAnimationStarted: true } , () => {
    console.log(this.state.hasAnimationStarted)
    console.log(this.state.animationStyle)

    });
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const x = 1024; // min value
    const y = 9999; // max value
    let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;
    let tranf = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
    var ani = {
      transform: tranf,
    };
    this.setState({ animationStyle: ani, hasAnimationStarted: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainbox">
        <div
          className="box"
          style={this.state.hasAnimationStarted ? this.state.animationStyle : {}}
        >
          <div className="box1">
            <span className="span1">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span2">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span3">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span4">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="box2">
            <span className="span1">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span2">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span3">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
            <span className="span4">
              <b>50</b>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button className="spin" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
          Spin
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this works

Comment: thanks Faisal, just a quick think, the wheel only works once, how can I wheel spin every time spin button press

Comment: after each click we need to check if animation has already running. if so then stop it and restart it.  check the following link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mtrps7?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

save the style object in local state in componentDidMount or directly into constructor.

```
componentDidMount() {
     var x = 1024; // min value
     var y = 9999; // max value
     let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;
     let tranf = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
     var ani = {
         transform: tranf,
     };
    this.setState ({animationStyle : ani , hasAnimationStarted : false });
}
```

then inside the onClick function set the value of your style like this

```
handleOnClick= () => this.setState({ hasAnimationStarted : true });
```

inside the component

```
<div className="box" style={ this.state.hasAnimationStarted? this.animationStyle : {} }>

    <button className="spin" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
         Spin
    </button>

</div>
```

so now if your hasAnimationStarted becomes true your extra style will be added

Comment: still its not working.. can you check this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ayn7fs?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: check my other answer